# Fullcalendar get events with jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, fullcalendar

I'm using JQuery FullCalendar version 1.5.4 and I want to set the events with JQuery.

I use $.getJSON to call a php file, that retreive my data in my MySQL database.

When I limit my query with limit 0,1  , everything works fine. The event is sucessfully displayed in the calendar. However, when my php return an array of object, I get the error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null`

the JSON data returned by my PHP Page looks like this :

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Halloween ","start":"2013-02-08 00:00:00","end":"2013-02-08 00:00:00","allDay":true},{"id":2,"title":null,"start":"2013-02-12 00:00:00","end":"2013-02-12 00:00:00","allDay":true},{"id":3,"title":"Sortie Valcartier","start":"2013-02-20 00:00:00","end":"2013-02-20 00:00:00","allDay":true}]
```

The PHP code looks like this :

```
<?php

//header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die (" NOPE . [" . mysql_error() . "]");
mysql_select_db("garderie");

$query = "select a.ActiviteID as ActiviteID,a.nom as Nom , cd.datedujour as Jour from activites a 
          inner join calendrieractivite ca 
          on a.activiteid = ca.activiteid
          inner join calendrierdate cd
          on ca.dateid = cd.dateid
        ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$events = array();

$i = 0;

$year = date('Y'); 
$month = date('m');

while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $ligne["ActiviteID"];
    $nom = $ligne["Nom"];


    $e = array(
        'id' => (int)$id,
        'title' => $nom,            
        'start' => $ligne["Jour"],//$start,
        'end' => $ligne["Jour"],
        'allDay' => true
    );
    $events[$i] = $e;

    $i++;        
}


mysql_close();

echo (json_encode($events));
?>
```

the jquery code looks like this

```
...
$.getJSON('json_events.php', null, function(data){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: data,
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to filter your events on the php side, and make sure every event has a title.  When you pass a null title to FullCalendar, it seems to break the script.

```
{"id":2,"title":null,"start":"2013-02-12 00:00:00","end":"2013-02-12 00:00:00","allDay":true}
```

Comment: Dave, the second event in the json you posted has a null title.

Comment: oh my god I think I might explode if it was only that. Unfortunately I can't test it before monday. Thanks